# Unable to install Dotnetnuke website

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

Im trying to install a DotNetNuke website(Version 7.01) .

Here is what i have accomplished till now.

1. Downloaded install version of DNN 7.01
2. Unzipped the DNN to a folder(foldername=dnntest) in my wwwroot
   folder.
3. Created a database of the same name(dnntest) in sql server 2008.

Now when i try to install the website it throws up this following error.

[image]

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBatw8mgPrg) for the installation.

**My Config:**

```
   IIS 8
   DNN version 7.01.02 Community edition
   Sql server 2008(64-bit version)
   Windows 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For DNN 7 you need to have ASP.Net 4.0 installed on IIS. Please check it.

Comment: Yes. thanks. It was a asp.net issue. Funny how you have to click this option and its not clicked by default when installing IIS